# How to build an Isolated Drupal instance for testing

Tags: drush, bootstrapping

In order to run DrupalWebTests on [travis-ci](https://travis-ci.org/), I need to build a new Drupal instance where these tests are ran.

Typically, one runs these tests with `drush -l http://localhost.example test-run SomeTest`

This, however, assumes Drupal installed, being served on http://localhost.example (a webserver) and it being connected to a database as set in `settings.php`, having simpletest enabled.

Typically, this means installing MySQL, Apache and installing and configuring Drupal. Those are heavy depedencies and doing so for each test-case or even just every build, will require a lot of overhead; a build server like Travis will need to install these servers for each test-run.

Drush has `drush run-server` to run a lightweight server. Drupal can run off a sqlite database, which would be extremely usefull for these tests.

Moreover: as far as I can make out, the actual web-tests are not ran from that Drupal-instance at `http://localhost.example`, but get a clean build and isolated database (as should be, when testing). It appears that the Fully-functional Drupal at http://localhost.example is merely used as bootstrap for the web-tests.

Can I circumvent that bootstrap in some way?

And if not, what is a quick and easy way to get a Drupal installed and serving with as little dependencies (like Apache/Nginx, MySQL etc) as possible?

Also note that I am running Travis already for [tagadelic](https://travis-ci.org/berkes/tagadelic), but so far, only for the phpunit tests. I want to extend this to run the DrupalWebTests there as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use different git branches to isolate your code tests.

```
git checkout -b iss_tst1
<make changes>
git add <changes>
git commit -m "my new changes" <changes>

git checkout -b iss_tst2
<make changes>
git add <changes>
git commit -m "other new independent changes" <changes>
```

Then you should be able to run independent tests on each branch.

Comment: You cannot use git branches in automated testing like that, without severely cluttering the actual git-workwflow. TDD, test-driven development, means running the test -isoated- hundreds of times per day.